# ¿Como se usa la directiva [style] de ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, angularjs-2.0, ionic2, angular-directivas

Alguna vez leí en una documentación que se podía usar una directiva style de ionic o angular, no recuerdo bien, solo recuerdo que era al así: `[style.width]='expresión'` y no logro dar con la documentación, ¿Alguien sabe como se usa?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:-

```
[style]="{'width': '100%'}";
```